# What is the IP Whitelist for Crashlytics (Fabric) servers along with ports and protocols information

Tags: firewall, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, whitelist

I am trying to deploy an iOS app with `crashlytics` in it. The organization runs a firewall, so have to give them whitelist specifics for `crashlytics`. I tried searching for it and got different answers like `23.23.121.187` , `174.129.19.57`, `23.21.247.165`.

I am not sure how to get this information. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which parts of Fabric and Crashlytics are you looking to use?

Answer (score 18):

I got the reply from the fabric support team. Their IP range changes frequently and so advised me to whitelist the following on ports `80` and `443`:

﻿`reports.crashlytics.com`
`settings.crashlytics.com`
`api.crashlytics.com`
`www.crashlytics.com`
`realtime.crashlytics.com`﻿
`e.crashlytics.com`

Hope this helps for people looking for it.

Comment: Someone know if these URL's are still valid?

Comment: Maybe @mikebonnell can help

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605068/whitelisting-fabric-crashlytics-ip and my recent interaction with support, it is suggested to whitelist all subdomains for the 2 domains.