# Whitelisting Fabric & Crashlytics IP

Tags: firewall, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

Question - would like to allow access to Fabric & Crashlytics from our server which means that we need to allow it through our firewall for access.
Can anyone share the domains or IPs that we should allow through ?

Secondly, we would also like the fabric plugin for Android Studio and Xcode to work, would the above domains and IPs also apply ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Mike from Fabric and Firebase here. We don't support IP whitelisting as our IP addresses can and do change quite frequently. You should whitelist the following domains:

```
*.crashlytics.com
*.fabric.io
```

**Update as of July 2020:**

From the recent contact with the Firebase team, we got the following details:

You can whitelist the following domains on ports 80 and 443:

For Firebase Crashlytics (SDK versions 4.x and up):

```
*.crashlytics.com
crashlyticsreports-pa.googleapis.com
```

For Fabric Crashlytics (SDK versions 3.x):

```
*.crashlytics.com
*.fabric.io
```

***For Firebase Crashlytics, there's one more domain which needs to be whitelisted even though it's not officially informed by Firebase team***

```
firebasecrashlyticssymbols.googleapis.com
```

Comment: Is this still the case since the acquisition by Firebase?

Comment: Correct, no changes.

Comment: @MikeBonnell what ports/protocols are used? 443-TCP?

Comment: Ports 80 and 443.

Comment: Hey, can anyone confirm that opening these domains is sufficient for proper crash reporting?

Comment: Mike, is this answer still correct after the Firebase migration?

Comment: Yes, still true.

Comment: Is this true for debugging symbols upload as per https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?

Comment: Update: yes it is (still) true. Whitelist ports 80 and 443 for the above 2 domains as well.

Comment: Is anyone else seeing requests to `firebaselogging-pa.googleapis.com`?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand a firewall usually blocks incoming connections, fabric just requires outgoing, so no need for whitelisting.

If you have a strict situation, just inpect the firewall logs with your sysadmin and make the whitelist entries, it can be different over time and you should be able to update it, so this way you know how to obtain it.

Comment: That's not what quite I'm after. I'd like a  list so we can add to the list in a very conclusive manner rather than provide ad-hoc entries into the firewall when something doesn't work.

Comment: Well it's a third party company, they can change domains as they like, so you have to be ready to change it ad-hoc. Personally I recommend Little Snitch, install it on an OS X machine and it will let you inspect the connections outgoing from Fabric & Crashlytics

Comment: Not true, firewall can be easily configured to block outgoing connections unless they are whitelisted, and this is actually done in many private networks.