# Whitelisting Firebase Crashlytics SDK

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, whitelist

I just finished a migration to the new Firebase Crashlytics SDK.

On the past I added rules in accordance to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605068/whitelisting-fabric-crashlytics-ip). But as you may notice it relates to the now deprecated Fabric alternative.

What is the newest update on this matter? Which domains should I whitelist if I want to allow the reports to go through a firewall.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the updated information:

For Firebase Crashlytics (SDK versions 4.x and up)

```
*.crashlytics.com
crashlyticsreports-pa.googleapis.com
```

For Fabric Crashlytics (SDK versions 3.x)

```
*.fabric.io
*.crashlytics.com
```

Comment: But why *.crashlytics.com?
(for firebase sdks)

Answer (score 1):

the endpoints at present time remain the same. However, at some point this year this will need to be updated.