# Android Crashlytics InterruptedIOException timeout

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I added Crashlytics to project build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0'
```

and to app build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:17.4.4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

Now i have this error after launching my app:

```
E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Settings request failed.
    java.io.InterruptedIOException: timeout
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.timeoutExit(RealCall.kt:384)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.maybeReleaseConnection(RealCall.kt:346)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.noMoreExchanges$okhttp(RealCall.kt:310)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:205)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:148)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:129)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.network.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:86)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:200)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:193)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzp.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:60)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: Canceled
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:72)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:197)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:148) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:129) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.network.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:86) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:200) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:193) 
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzp.run(Unknown Source:2) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:60) 
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

What i've tried:

- rebuilding the project
- invalidating Android Studio caches
- downloading and updating google-services.json
- adding ext.enableCrashlytics = true to build.gradle

But i have no result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crashlytics Fabric : Failed to execute task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197659/crashlytics-fabric-failed-to-execute-task)

Comment: Is your phone's internet access ok ?

Comment: @JavadDehban i tried all solutions from there and none of them helped

Comment: @matdev yep, internet requests to our server work

Comment: then is your server's internet access ok ?

Comment: I would recommend adding these domains to your whitelist (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61897186/whitelisting-firebase-crashlytics-sdk/61900106#61900106), incase this is a network issue. However, this could be an issue on the Crashlytics end as well, at which point you should write in to Firebase Support (https://firebase.google.com/support) so they can take a look at your apps details in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this error only happens in debug flavors. According Firebase Support the solutions should be:

> Since you are using different app flavor, you should have different package names for each >flavor: com.example.prod and com.example.debug.
> These should configured in the console as different apps.

Answer (score 1):

it's okay now. And i did nothing. Apparently it was a temporary problem on the Firebase side